# Is there any method to resize the entire plot as well as the font size and the line width in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

There are many ways to change or set the figure size or the subplot size in `matplotlib` or `seaborn`, but as long as the size of a figure changes, say, becomes bigger, the font size, the line width, and the marker size will become relatively shorter visually. Therefore I wonder is there any method to resize the plot but keep all those things unchanged. It looks a bit like a scaling function in many pic-apps, but those scalings cannot enhance the pic quality while replotting the pic can.

Comment: Hi, show us the code, which you were using to enlarge plots

Comment: @404pio I don't think code is important to this question. If you ask, the code may be as simple as `sns.displot(data=data, x='duration', kde=True)` or `ax.plot(x,y)`. The key point is how to enlarge the plots as well as all the sizes such as the font size and the line width etc. (the font size of the tick label and legend, for example). Of course, I can change all the font sizes manually but I wonder whether there's a better or more elegant method. Thanks.

Comment: I think, that code is important in this question - we will get starting point.

Comment: Rather than change the size, increase the dpi when you call savefig.  Then adjust the size of the output as you see fit.

Comment: @JodyKlymak oH yes, that's it! I've tried changing the dpi while calling `savefig` and the quality of the pic enhanced and the visual relative size had no change compared to the original one. That's what I'm asking for. You can make an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Besides, directly changing the `rcParams` such as `plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 1000` is a more elegant way if there're many pics to save and all of them require higher qualities.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sns.set()` property. Here is the sample code that may help you to understand.

This is with normal font.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True)
```

[image: Normal Fonts]

This is with Bigger font.

```py
sns.set(font_scale=3)  # crazy big
g = sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True)
g.fig.set_figwidth(18.27)
g.fig.set_figheight(11.7)
```

[image: Bigger Font]